# Windows Batch file error: 'unexpected at this time' error

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I get an error for my batch code

```
was unexpected at this time
```

I have removed all the comments and matched all opening brackets with counter closing ones, but still getting the same error.

What does the error mean?

Comment: You're going to need to post some code for us to assist.

Comment: That is clearly a synthax error. Can you post the part of the code that is throwing this error? Probably a little thing that sliped your attention.

Comment: The most probable cause is a variable value %varname% used inside parentheses. To solve that, replace %varname% by !varname! and add this line at beginning: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: @Aacini Might be a bit dumb to ask, but why? What does the !! do that %% wont?

Comment: @GarethJones: I elaborate on this topic in my answer below...

Comment: @GarethJones: `!!` will expand later that `%%` so even an empty variable will work at `if !emptyVar!==One ...` but the same with `%emptyVar%` will fail

Answer (score 3):

The most probable cause of this error is a %variable% expansion used inside parentheses, because in this case the expanded value is the one the variable had *before* entering the  ( block ). A simple example:

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
   set /P input=Enter input value: 
   if %input% == One (
      echo Option "one" selected
   )
   if %input% == Two (
      echo Option "two" selected
   )
   . . .
)
```

In previous example the %input% value is always expanded to nothing because that variable does not exist before the FOR loop executed, so the if's are expanded to `if == One (` and cause the above mentioned error.  Remember that %var% expansion is achieved *just one time* when the command to execute is parsed before the execution. In this case, the *command to execute* is the external FOR, so all %var% expansions included into it *at any level* have this effect.

The way to solve this problem is via *Delayed Expansion*, that is, include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning and replace all %var% expansions by !var! ones. This way, the value of !var! variable will be expanded *each time* the command in which it appear be executed. Type `set /?` and `cmd /?` for further details on this topic.